# Show messages using Thymeleaf in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using thymeleaf and spring 3 mvc. 
When I try to perform Ajax POST request I don't understand how can I show a response message from a controller on my html page:

Here's a code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/settings",
    data: "request=" + request,
    success: function (response) {
        $('#msg').replaceWith('<div id="msg" th:text="response"></div>');
    },
});
```

'response' is a i18n message from controller. Now, I want to show this message at  using thymeleaf (th:text="response"). Of course, this code does not work, because it thinks that response variable is a plain string.

The question is how to show i18n response message using thymeleaf. Or maybe there are some other methods to show i18n messages on html page (not using jsp) through js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf attributes (such as th:text) will only be parsed and replaced on the server. Since this ajax response is processed on the browser, th:text will not process. If "settings" is already a Thymeleaf-resolved page, it is likely already i18n'd and you can simply do something like:

```
$('#msg').html(response);
```

However, if you are truly looking for client-side javascript processing of Thymeleaf tags, consider [Thymol](http://sourceforge.net/u/jjbenson/wiki/thymol/).